# New variable conditional on whether a df1 column value equals any value included in a specific df2 column

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I am trying to make a new variable using `mutate()` . In df1, I have ranges of values in col1, col2, col3, and col4. I would like to create a new binary variable in df1 that is "1" **IF** any of the col1-4 values are found in a specific df2 column (let's say col10).

Thanks!

This is what I have tried so far, but I don't think it is returning a value of "1" for all matching value, only some of them.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(newvar = case_when(
    col1 == df2$col10 | col2 == df2$col10 | col3 == df2$col10 | col4 == df2$col10 ~ 1
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make some dummy data.  `df1` has 4 columns and `df2` has one column named `col10`.  In the dummy data, rows 1,2,3 and 5 have matches in `df2$col10`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2=3:7, col3=5:9, col4=10:14)

df2 <- data.frame(col10 = c(1,2,3,14))
```

We can use `rowwise()` to do computations within each row and then `c_across()` to identify that variables of interest.  The code identifies whether any of the values in the four columns are in `df2$col10` and returns a logical value.  The `as.numeric()` turns that logical value into 0 (`FALSE`) and 1 (`TRUE`).

```r
df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(newvar = as.numeric(any(c_across(col1:col4) %in% df2$col10)))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    col1  col2  col3  col4 newvar
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1     1     3     5    10      1
#> 2     2     4     6    11      1
#> 3     3     5     7    12      1
#> 4     4     6     8    13      0
#> 5     5     7     9    14      1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could use `if_any` here.  If the number of rows are the same, use `==` for elementwise comparison instead of `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(newvar = +(if_any(col1:col4,  ~.x %in% df2$col10)))
```